# Jena ARQ update or insert using Fuseki?

Tags: jena, fuseki, arq

What is the difference between "update" and "insert" in Jena ARQ documentation when using FUseki? For example, if I need to add to a Fuseki database (or graph) a simple statement, should I use UpdateExecutionFactory.createRemote method or [ARQ - SPARQL Update](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/query/update.html)?.

Answer (score 1):

An "Update" is a SPARQL Update operation.

An "Update Request" is a number of SPARQL Update operations, separate by ";" all sent at once.

"INSERT" is one of the SPARQL Update verbs - there are other things you can do in SPARQL Update like delete data or work on whole graphs.

In addition, adding data to a dataset or graph can be referred to called "inserting".